# Can loadHTMLString load image asynchronously?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview

I have a local template and generate a complete html string by inserting result of a web API call into the template. The html string has some links to external images.

I'm showing the string in a UIWebView by calling its loadHTMLString method as below ...

```
   self.newsBodyWebView.loadHTMLString(unifiedDoc, baseURL: nil)
```

I'm not quite clear about loadHTMLString's behavior, it appears that it's rendering contents synchronously, like even if I'm sure that the text part has already returned, the UIWebView won't show any content (I'm seeing a blank white view) until the external images are downloaded completely.

Could you please suggest what I can do in this scenario? I'm thinking if I should put different sections of text and images into different UITableViewCell to separate their display, this does not seem like a tidy solution though.

Comment: Hi Ripley , did you find a solution for this? I'm facing the same issue with some my project right now